# How can I delete the crash logs from Crashlytics?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Is there a way in Google Cloud Platform to delete all the crashlytics logs that are present? I did some testing and now would like to delete them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, however if you write in to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support), they can delete all of your crash logs associated with a particular build.